# Is it possible to open a Private Browser window in Safari using Terminal.app?

Tags: terminal, safari, bash

I'm trying to open a Private Browser window in Safari using Terminal. I could open Safari using open command and this way, `open /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari` but I couldn't open a Private Browser window.

Please suggest how to open a Private Browser window from the command line.

Answer (score 5):

Note: This is only one possible method. It works by simulating the pressing of <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>. You can also simulate the pressing of the menu item, but the script is longer.

Create a new file, and paste in these contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    delay 0.5
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "n" using {command down, shift down}
    end tell
end tell
```

Save it somewhere (here, I'll pretend it's called `myscript`).

In Terminal, find the file and make it executable:

```
chmod +x myscript
```

Simply run it to create a new private window in Safari

```
./myscript
```

If you want to be able to use this script regardless of your current working directory, create an alias *OR* move it to `/usr/local/bin`.

If you want an alias, use

```
alias myscript='/path/to/script/myscript
```

You can add this line to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` to automatically load this alias when you start Terminal.